# Form cleaned_data and getting values

Tags: django, forms, cleaned-data

I have problem because I'm using smart select ( 3 select fields )to filter my table.
But engine id is wrong and don't get correct query. I need to get no id from db but common names.

views.py

```
def spec_list(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = SpecForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        mark = form.cleaned_data['mark']
        model = form.cleaned_data['model']
        engine = form.cleaned_data['engine']
        all_datap = Spec.objects.filter(mark=mark).filter(model=model).filter(engine=engine)
        return render(request, 'specyfikacja/specyfikacja.html', {'form': form,'all_datap' : all_datap})
else:
    form = SpecForm()
return render(request, 'specyfikacja/specyfikacja.html', {'form': form})
```

From

```
mark = form.cleaned_data['mark']
```

I'm getting id like "1" but need name like "porshe"

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Mark(models.Model):
    mark = models.CharField(max_length = 60)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.mark)

class Model(models.Model):
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark)
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.model)

class Engine(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.engine)


class Spec(models.Model):
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark)
    model = ChainedForeignKey(Model, chained_field = "mark", chained_model_field = "mark", show_all = False, auto_choose= True)
    engine = ChainedForeignKey(Engine, chained_field = "model", chained_model_field = "model", auto_choose= True)
    oe = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    plt = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    szer = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    zr = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    r = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    rim = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.mark)
```

forms.py

```
class SpecForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Spec
        fields = ('mark','model','engine')
```

template

```
<div class="subnav">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="span3">
            {{ form.mark }}
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            {{ form.model }}
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            {{ form.engine }}
        </div>
        <div class="span1"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Pobierz" /></div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share the form code too, please

Comment: Ok. Im edited 1 post.

Comment: why do you need the name in the view ?

Comment: Im geting names in select form but when submiting im geting id.

Its working that 
Choose model then geting mark then engine and engine id its from engine model and its wrong becouse in spec model its other id. But when i will be able to search names then all will be good. so I'm thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

because "engine" is not an object and just a string... try...

```
all_datap = Spec.objects.filter(mark__id=mark, model=model, engine__engine=engine).distinct()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Now error: Join on field 'engine' not permitted. Did you misspell 'engine' for the lookup type?